# overflow:scroll is not working in Android mobile phones

Tags: android, html, css

HI I use overflow:scroll for scrolling in my application but it is not working in Android mobile phone. I don't know what is the reason but when I am searching in the net it is shows the Android version 3.0 below phone does not support the overflow:scroll. Please suggest an approach how to use scrolling in my application for Andoriod phones below 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use the [ScrollView](http://www.androidaspect.com/2012/02/scrollview-tutorial-android-ui.html) like this in your application. Also remember that android scrollview can hold only one view in it. So, if you want to have more than one view inside a scrollView put all those Views(ImageView, TextView, OtherLayouts etc) inside a single Layout and wrap it with the ScrollView.